# CID from search, PLACES

Tags: google-places-api, google-play

in my app I have to do two calls to api search for get param CID:

- Search places from location
- Get references of places, and call again with this reference.
- Get url(with cid)

Is possible get CID in the first call(search from location)? Only I get for each result:
-reference
-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only possible to retreive CID using the process described above. If you believe that returning the CID in the initial Place Search Request would be a useful feature you can submit a 'Places API - Feature Request' [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).